# How to get te productid for the uber sdk in an android app?

Tags: android

I want to integrate UBER sdk in my application for that I am using [this](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk) sdk. I am getting clientId from uber developers, but I don't know, what is the product_id here and how can I get it.

Any idea?

Comment: Your question is wonderful, see these minor formal changes to make it perfect.

Answer (score 0):

According to the iOS UberRides SDK doc

```
/**
 Add a specific product ID to the deeplink. You can see product ID's for a given
 location with the Rides API `GET /v1/products` endpoint.

 - parameter productID: Unique identifier of the product to populate in pickup
 */
```